# How to call a bean method when mouse over on a graphicImage?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, mouseover, actionmethod, graphicimage

I have the requirement that on mouse over of a `<p:graphicImage>` a JSF backing bean method should be called which will display some data dynamically.

How can I achieve this? Please don't suggest me JavaScript code.

Comment: No way without javascript. Java runs at server-side, and you need some JavaSCript to send a request to your server when mouse hovers.

Comment: JSF/PrimeFaces use under the covers *loads* of JavaScript code in order to achieve the ajax magic and dynamic look'n'feel. Do you really not want to make use of it? Or did you actually mean that you don't want to manually write "plain vanilla JavaScript" for it? In any way, just don't make this kind of nonsensicial statements in the future questions.

Comment: @JBNizet, JSF components already add the JS needed to perform their work (and for some of them it means ajax requests).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This link](http://www.horstmann.com/corejsf/jsf-tags.html#Table4_12) shows that `<h:graphicImage>` supports the `mouseover` event. Since you are using Primefaces, you should be able to do something like

```
<h:graphicImage ...>
    <p:ajax event="mouseover" actionListener="myMethod"/>
</h:graphicImage>
```